# Is it possible to have an if function use pattern matching in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, matching

I know that a method that takes a list input can use pattern matching like so:

```
testingMethod [] = "Blank"
testingMethod (x:xs) = show x
```

My question is, can I do this with an if function? For example, if I have a function1 that needs to check the pattern of the output from function2, how would I go about doing this? I am looking for something like this:

```
if (function2 inputInt == pattern((x:xs), [1,2,3])) then
```

Is this possible to do in haskell?

Comment: You can use a *pattern guard* for this.

Comment: And `(==)` will not work, since `(==)` is actually "*just an ordinary function*" (well of course with some constraints).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Wow, I've not heard of these before, this is very cool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is that of a case statement or a guard:

You said:

```
if (function2 inputInt == pattern((x:xs), [1,2,3])) then
```

In Haskell:

```
testingMethod inputInt | (x:xs, [1,2,3]) <- function2 inputInt = expr
                       | otherwise = expr2
```

Or using `case` and `let` (or you could inline things or use `where`):

```
testingMethod inputInt =
    let res = function2 inputInt
    in case res of
         (x:xs, [1,2,3]) -> expr
         _ -> expr2
```

Or using view patterns:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
testingMethod (function2 -> (x:xs,[1,2,3])) = expr
testingMethod _ = expr2
```

Comment: I use view patterns only when I'm using `PatternSynonyms`, and I have to look up the syntax every single time. I absolutely hate those things and wish we had a better alternative.

Comment: There's also `MultiWayIf`.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching in a function definition is simply syntactic sugar for the "fundamental" pattern matching provided by `case`. For example, let's desugar your first function:

```
testingMethod [] = "Blank"
testingMethod (x:xs) = show x
```

Can be rewritten to:

```
testingMethod arg = case arg of
  [] -> "Blank"
  (x:xs) -> show x
```

It's not so clear what you intend your second snippet to do, so I can't really show you how it would look with a `case` expression. But one possible interpretation would be something like this:

```
case function2 inputInt of
  ((x:xs), [1,2,3]) -> -- ...
  (_, _) -> -- ...
```

This supposes that your `function2` returns a tuple of two lists.